# How can I prevent Backblaze from rescanning my disks before it finishes uploading the files it queued for upload during the last disk scan?

Tags: windows, backblaze

I have a fair amount of data in my disks to back up to Backblaze. Backblaze first scans my disks, starts uploading for a few hours or days, then at some point decides to rescans my disks, which takes many hours. I don't want that: I want Backblaze to first finish uploading before rescanning disks.

How can I prevent Backblaze from rescanning my disks before it finishes uploading the files it queued for upload during the last disk scan?

I use Backblaze with Windows 10.